Problems with Python installation after upgrade to Windows 11
I recently upgraded a PC from Win10 to Win11.  There are strange things happening with the Python installation(s) on the PC.  It has Python 3.11 and 3.12 installed.  I can run Python from the Command Prompt using python3.12, python3.11 or py.  But python or python3 do not work.  When I try "where python" it returns nothing.
Python3.11 is installed in C:\Users\WayneKozun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0
and 3.12 is installed in
C:\Users\WayneKozun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0
There is a python.exe and a python3.exe file in C:\Users\WayneKozun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps but when you try to run these they start the Windows Store and try to get you to install Python3.12.
The python3.11.exe and python3.12.exe in this folder work properly.
How do I fix this mess?
Re-Installed Python3.12 and it didn't help

Python installer by default puts it under py not under python. You can add an environment variable with that name and a link. Maybe you did this previously with your win10 install?
